# Hessian used for calculating GDIIS error vectors

Tags: geometry-optimization, geometry

GDIIS (Geometry optimisation with Direct Inversion of Iterative Subspace) is a well known method used by many QM codes for geometry optimisation. It is inspired from the almost universal DIIS method for converging SCF. The GDIIS method interpolates and extrapolates using the previous geometries and their gradients to obtain a new geometry that minimizes an error vector.

The error vector in GDIIS at $i$th is expressed as (in [this](https://schlegelgroup.wayne.edu/Pub_folder/251.pdf) paper):
$$e_i = H^{-1}f_i$$

where the $f_i$ is the force (negative of gradient) at geometry $x_i$ and $H$ is the estimated Hessian. Then the procedure involves minimizing $\sum c_i e_i$ with some constraints, and after some maths, GDIIS generates the new geometry guess $x_{i+1}$.

**I am confused about what the value of $H$ is supposed to be - is it supposed to be the Hessian at the current step ($x_i$) for all the previous points? Or is it supposed to be the Hessian at $i$th step for $e_i$ (but the Hessian symbol has no subscript)?**

The QChem [manual](https://manual.q-chem.com/4.3/sect0080.html) mentions that early version of GDIIS often used a static matrix (the starting Hessian or unit matrix) as $H$ in all cases. However, convergence is faster if a Hessian update scheme is used. This would indicate different Hessians used for different error vectors. But even in that page, the Hessian has not subscript. So I assume it means the Hessian at the current point has to be used for calculating the error vectors in the previous steps?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you read later in the paper you link to it says "The GDIIS method can perform satisfactorily with a constant Hessian. For an N-dimensional quadratic potential energy surface and N + 1 points that span the space, GDIIS will predict the exact minimum independent of the value of the Hessian (provided the Hessian is not singular). However,
updating the Hessian in a fashion similar to quasi-Newton methods can improve the performance." It then goes on to discuss Hessian update methods

Comment: @IanBush Yes, but what does that sentence mean? It performs better if you update the Hessian, so does that mean use each updated Hessian for each geometry to get error vectors, or use the last updated Hessian for all geometries. That's not clear to me and that's question I'm asking.

Comment: I read it as it doesn't matter, provided your estimate of the Hessian is not totally stupid it doesn't matter what you use, but the better guess you can provide for the current geometry, the better the performance will be. I also agree it's not the clearest write up I have ever read.

Answer (score 4):

According to my notes, which may be wrong, the Hessian is the (updated) Hessian at iteration k, i.e. the error vectors are re-defined in each iteration. I guess the argument is that the most recent updated Hessian has the most information. Whether this is what is actually implemented in various codes is difficult to know without actually looking into the codes.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Unfortunately I haven't found any open source software that implements GDIIS so that I could look at the code, so I have to go by the original publication.

Comment: @SRMaiti I found a python library that seems to use this GDIIS method. So it maybe useful for you to see some source code here: https://github.com/RimoAccelerator/KST48/blob/main/kst48.py#L701

Comment: @VandanRevanur Thank you, that is helpful